# About C function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int add(int x,int y,int z){
    return x+z+y;
}
int main(){
    float w = printf("%d\n", add(40, 40, 55));
    printf("%f",w);
    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone explain the value of 'w' as 4?

Comment: Read what [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) *returns*.

Comment: Your program does 2 unnecessary conversions. `printf()` returns an int, it's converted to float to assign to `w`. Afterwards it's converted to double as argument of a function accepting a variable number of arguments. I suggest you stick with `int` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

from [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

> Return value
>
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
>   characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
>   strings).

in your example your `printf` prints `135` and a '`\n'` thus giving `4`

try different variations and see

```
float w=printf("%d\n",add(40,40,55));
printf("%f\n",w);

 w=printf("%d\n",add(40,0,5));
printf("%f\n",w);

 w=printf("%d\n",add(0,0,5));
printf("%f\n",w);
```

---

on a completely different note `w` should have been an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Return value of `printf` is number of characters printed.

Hence

`float w=printf("%d\n",add(40,40,55));`

same as

`float w=printf("135\n");`

So total 4 characters including `\n`.